# Как делать полупрозрачный круг около персонажа, когда тот за объектом(стеной к примеру)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно пустить луч от камеры к персонажу и изменять прозрачность объекта, но при таком способе полупрозрачным делается весь объект.

Как делать полупрозрачность только вокруг персонажа?

К примеру могу привести похожую систему в project zomboid (плохой пример)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Фантазия программиста не знает границ, придумай свое решение )

Comment: Вероятнее всего это решается только шейдерами.

Comment: В играх без Unity это так делается. Берём `Canvas`, берём координат игрока на `Canvas`-е. Считаем радиус и берём все пиксели которые нужно сделать прозрачным. И в этих пикселях красим соответствующим цветом земли. Но вот как это на Unity реализовать это проблема.

Comment: Есть возможность получить `Canvas` в виде `Texture2D`?

Comment: Canvas переводить в текстуру 2д не вижу смысла и без понятия как, скорее всего это делается с шейдерами

Comment: Это достаточно сложный эффект, и придется немного потрудиться, чтобы добиться его, нужно писать шейдеры, вот здесь хорошо рассказано как добиться такого эффекта: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152824/how-can-i-create-a-see-behind-walls-effect
если у вас нет времени так заморачиваться и вы с шейдерами на вы, то могу предложить дешевую но сердитую альтернативу: сферкастить к персонажу от камеры и отключать прорисовку попавших пот хит мешей